# Substrate node-template Compiling sp-externalities error: cannot find macro `thread_local` in this scope

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust, substrate-contracts-node

When I am trying to build substrate node-template, `cargo build` below error occurs. How to solve this issue.

system : `Apple M1 Pro`
OSX : `Ventura 13.2.1`

rustup show

```
installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-apple-darwin

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin (overridden by +toolchain on the command line)
rustc 1.70.0-nightly (f63ccaf25 2023-03-06)
```

```
  error: cannot find macro `thread_local` in this scope
    --> /Users/xxxxx/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/f38bd66/primitives/externalities/src/scope_limited.rs:22:1
     |
  22 | environmental::environmental!(ext: trait Externalities);
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: `thread_local` is in scope, but it is an attribute: `#[thread_local]`
     = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::thread_local_impl` which comes from the expansion of the macro `environmental::environmental` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0425]: cannot find value `GLOBAL` in this scope
    --> /Users/xxxxxxx/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/f38bd66/primitives/externalities/src/scope_limited.rs:22:1
     |
  22 | environmental::environmental!(ext: trait Externalities);
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
     |
     = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::environmental` which comes from the expansion of the macro `environmental::environmental` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
  error: could not compile `sp-externalities` due to 4 previous errors
```

Comment: Check you are using the same versions of substrate in all your repository, check the version in the runtime/Cargo.toml , pallets/template/Cargo.toml and node/Cargo.toml

Comment: thanks for replying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue sounds like it might be an environment issue. I notice you are running the x86_64 version of Rust on your Mac. I have an M1 chip as well, and have no issues using the ARM target, so I'd start with installing and using the `*-aarch64-apple-darwin` toolchains for both stable and nightly. Install the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` targets after that and try again.

Comment: thanks for replay, I was using Rosetta it was issue :)